# Unable to run corda tests from IntelliJ

Tags: corda

When I select and run a test, the build fails with the message: 
*"Kotlin: Usage of '@JvmDefault' is only allowed if the flag -Xenable-jvm-default is enabled"* for the following files.

```
    corda/serialization/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/serialization/internal/OrdinalIO.kt
    corda/serialization/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/serialization/internal/SerializationFormat.kt
    corda/serialization/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/serialization/internal/amqp/AMQPSerializer.kt
```

I have cloned corda from my fork of corda/corda on github, and am on branch **master**, opened in IntelliJ as per instructions on the docsite. The **JDK version is 1.8.0_152** and the **Kotlin plugin** is on version **1.2.41**. I see that the -Xenable-jvm-default is enabled in the corda/build.gradle file. There are no local changes. Could you please advise on what I missed or need to do to fix this?

Comment: Can you try invalidating the caches and restarting? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html

Comment: Thank you Joel, invalidating and re-starting the IntelliJ cache fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by invalidating IntelliJ's caches and restarting IntelliJ. See jetbrains.com/help/rider/Cleaning_System_Cache.html.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the gradle runner to execute the tests on **IntelliJ**.

- Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner (or search for runner)
- Windows: this is in “Settings”
- MacOS: this is in “Preferences”
- Set “Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle” to true
- Set “Run test using:” to “Gradle Test Runner”